# Rails loop through array don't show duplicate strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looping through an array of id's like so:

```
<% @tip.horse_ids.each do |i| %>
  <% @horse = Horse.find(i) %>
  <%= @horse.race.meeting.racecourse.strip %><br />
  <%= @horse.race.time.to_s(:time) %> - <%= @horse.name.strip %><br />
<% end %>
```

Which outputs something like this:

```
Kempton (AW)
01:30 - Light Gunner
Kempton (AW)
01:30 - Mesophere
Kempton (AW)
01:30 - Ragtag Rascal
Kempton (AW)
01:30 - Many Waters
Kempton (AW)
02:40 - Judicial
Stratford
01:40 - Rabunda
Stratford
```

I only want "Kempton (AW)" to appear once in the loop (the first one) and same for the time so "1:30" should only appear once too I want to remove all the duplicated content. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `uniq`

```
@tip.horse_ids.uniq.each do |i|
```

or better yet

```
<% Horse.where(id: @tip.horse_ids).each do |horse| <%
  <%= horse.race.meeting.racecourse.strip %><br />
<% end %>
```

and even better, you should have access to `horses` if everything is set up correctly.

```
<% @tip.horses.each do |horse| <%
  <%= horse.race.meeting.racecourse.strip %><br />
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a uniq to your array would solve your problem

```
<% @tip.horse_ids.uniq.each do |i| %>
  <% @horse = Horse.find(i) %>
  <%= @horse.race.meeting.racecourse.strip %><br />
  <%= @horse.race.time.to_s(:time) %> - <%= @horse.name.strip %><br />
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has a similar problem to this the way I fixed it was by using group_by

```
<% @tip.horses.group_by(&:meeting).each do |meeting, horses| %>
  <%= meeting.racecourse %><br />
  <% horses.each do |horse| %>
    <%= horse.race.race_time %> - <%= horse.name %><br />
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```